# pocket api request failing - missing consumer key

Tags: pocket

could anyone help me understand what's wrong with this request to pocket?

`curl -Li 
    http://getpocket.com/v3/oauth/request
    -X POST 
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
    -H "X-Accept: application/json" 
   -d "{\"consumer_key\":\"xxxx-xxxxxxxxx\",\"redirect_uri\":\"http://www.google.com\"}"`

I get a

```
< X-Error: Missing consumer key.
< X-Error-Code: 138
```

back.

the `xxxx` bits are really the key I got from the website when I created my App, and I've also tried with and without the `-Li` options on `curl` but it makes no difference.

I've followed the guide from [here](http://www.jamesfmackenzie.com/getting-started-with-the-pocket-developer-api/) - I'm sure I've made a dumb typo somewhere, but I can't see where it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `https`, [as per API](https://getpocket.com/developer/docs/authentication):

> All calls to the Pocket Authentication API should be done over HTTPS.

Comment: this works... big thanks for the help, I've accepted the answerr